# How to run .sh through terminal without using Nautilus Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: command-line, bash, nautilus, java, .sh

I have an .sh file that looks like

```
#!bin/bash
exec /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/
java java -jar /home/me/myfolder/my.jar
```

I've made this file executable and it works fine when in the "nautilus" desktop, but when I run it on just normal desktop (Ubuntu 14.04) it only opens with gedit. I have also tried opening it with Java 7 and Java 6, but it does not give me the option to run in terminal. Also when i'm in the terminal and cd to the folder containing the .jar file and run it that also works fine. What I'm looking for is a way to just double click my .sh file without having to go to nautilus first. Is this possible?

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I cant find the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the difference between a nautilus desktop and a "normal" desktop. It is both nautilus.

Comment: Maybe I'm using the wrong term then because in order for me to execute that file I have to go into the terminal sudo nautilus and then another file manager comes up. When I double click it in the new file manager it executes correctly and does not open to the gpedit

Comment: Eek. Nautilus has this preference settings for handling executable files. It looks like your "root" nautilus has this set to "always run", and your own has this set to "always view".

Answer (score 0):

When you have made it executable with `chmod +x file/name.sh`, you can run it by typing `./file/name.sh` in terminal.

Edit:
Actually just read what you where trying to do. Try commenting out the "exec" line of the script, and change the second line to `./home/me/myfolder/my.jar` after you have run `chmod +x /home/me/myfolder/my.jar`.

I don't know much about java, but I have run some java programs like this.

Comment: Yes that is correct, but can I just double click my .sh and it run automatically? I'm trying to make this easy for people not familiar with linux or the terminal at all.

Comment: Edited my answer a bit. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a desktop file and make it executable, then run it from nautilus or desktop directly. Here is an example:

Create a file using:

```
gedit myjar.desktop
```

Copy and paste the code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application  
Terminal=false
Exec=java -jar my.jar
Name=My Java Gui
Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/openjdk-7.png
#Path=/$HOME/
```

Some entries like path are optional.

Make it executable:

```
chmod +x myjar.desktop
```

Run it from nautilus.

Comment: Maybe I'll have to retrace some steps the terminal is telling me its either invalid or corrupted. Thanks for you help